# reduce size of videos

Tags: storage, video

Videos made on my android device have a size of about 70 MByte per minute.

How  to reduce to size of the videos?

I guess (but don't know) that a clever CPU intensive transformation with a better output codec could make the file size much smaller.

The recoding can happen on the device itself or on a Ubuntu PC.

Comment: Have you tried different resolutions, or do you want to retain the resolution  yet reduce the size?

Comment: @Firelord I would like to keep the resolution.